# trigger power automate to copy a sharepoint page and prefix page name

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I'm trying to get a power automate (SharePoint 365) for me to be able to;
from Site Pages, select a page, click power automate from the ribbon, and select a process which will automatically copy the SharePoint page, with same properties and contents, however append "DEV_" to the name. The Page should be saved in the exact same spot as the original.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to this article to copy SharePoint page:https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/copy-sharepoint-page-another-site-collection-using-power-tirta-wijaya?articleId=6691436585734463488

[image]

Comment: I'll try this out, and see how it works, thank you!

Comment: i keep running into this issue:
 "status": 400,
  "message": "Failed to verify the existence of source object at 'https://SharePointDomainName.sharepoint.com/sites/CollaborationDemoTest/8' due to error 'The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)'.\r\nclientRequestId: 664defe4-0731-4a71-b25d-206380554822\r\nserviceRequestId: 664defe4-0731-4a71-b25d-206380554822"

Answer (score 0):

The list id of the site pages library can be seen i the URL when you go to library settings. If you see %7B in the beginning and %7D in the end. Remove those. They are not part of the id but encodes { and }. This is my flow to copy one page. Just remove the filter query to copy all.

[image: Power Automate flow]